# Rails server reduce verbosity?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

One method of debugging within the Controllers I have learnt from Django is to actually print out variables within the controllers itself. However, I realize that this method is not as practical in rails as the default rails webserver is pretty verbose and it's making me difficult to trace.

FYI I read about the rails debugging page but most of those debug techniques exist in the VIEW layer (like <% @myvar.debug %>). I want to be able to see the state of vars inside the controllers and I don't want to use the rails debugger as it's kind of an overkill for something so simple.

My question is: is there a variable that I can set to reduce statements like those below from being produced at each page serve?

```
Started POST "/submissions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-06-02 02:35:38 -0400
  Processing by SubmissionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"U+I2mSfCRFvOyT/L82TTzsVRVJQuJbB+X3SaMWr/IM4=", "submission"=>{"url"=>"http://wasdvasd.com", "receiver_id"=>"1", "comment"=>"asdvasdvasdv"}, "commit"=>"Create Submission"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Link Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "links".* FROM "links" WHERE "links"."url" = 'http://wasdvasd.com' LIMIT 1
  AREL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "links" ("url", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ('http://wasdvasd.com', '2011-06-02 06:35:38.399463', '2011-06-02 06:35:38.399463')
  AREL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "submissions" ("link_id", "author_id", "receiver_id", "comment", "visited", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (5, 1, 1, 'asdvasdvasdv', NULL, '2011-06-02 06:35:38.402094', '2011-06-02 06:35:38.402094')
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/submissions
Completed 302 Found in 244ms
```

Comment: Just clear your terminal before each debug? The variable will then be at the top of the latest output. Generally this is a one-off thing. Cmd+K on Mac clears the terminal for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to change the logging level in your `config/environments/*.rb` files.

See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels for the different log levels.